# Shopping Cart PHP display error

Tags: php, cart

I am making a shopping cart for university project and following tutors sample code but tweaking it to fit my own design.

my site products are named such as

```
cutecupcak.es/product.php?id=vanilla_cupcakes
```

rather than

```
cutecupcak.es/product.php?id=2
```

The code for the shopping cart page to display the products in your cart is

```
if(is_numeric($id)) {
    $cartresult = mysql_query($sql);
```

but my product urls are NOT numeric and so the shopping cart is not displaying the results, as you can see here -- http://cutecupcak.es/shoppingcart.php - if you test it out.

it will work if you have `products.php?id=2` etc. though

what do i need to change from - `is_numeric` to make it work with my url format?

full code

```
<?php

session_start(); // start new session or call exisiting session
include('include/dbconnect.php'); // include the database connections

function renderCartForm()
    {
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
    if ($cart) {
        $items = explode(',',$cart);
        $contents = array();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $contents[$item] = (isset($contents[$item])) ? $contents[$item] + 1 : 1;
        }
        $output[] = '<form action="shoppingcart.php?action=update" method="post" id="cart">';
        $output[] = '<div class="form">';
        $output[] = '<table border="2" class="formcontainer">';
        $output[] = '<tr class="formlabels">';
        $output[] = '<td width="400">Cake Name</td>';
        $output[] = '<td width="75">Price</td>';
        $output[] = '<td width="75">Quantity</td>';
        $output[] = '<td width="100">Total</td>';
        $output[] = '<td width="100">Remove?</td>';
        $output[] = '</tr>';
        foreach ($contents as $id=>$qty) {
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `CAKE` WHERE `cake_url` = '.$id;

            if(is_numeric($id)) {
                $cartresult=mysql_query($sql);

            while($cartrow = mysql_fetch_array($cartresult)) {
                $output[] = '<tr>';
                $output[] = '<td>'.$cartrow['cake_name'].'</td>';
                $output[] = '<td>'.$cartrow['cake_price'].'</td>';
                $output[] = '<td><input type="text" name="qty'.$id.'" value="'.$qty.'" size="2" maxlength="2" /></td>';
                $output[] = '<td>&pound;'.($cartrow['cake_price'] * $qty).'</td>';
                $output[] = '<td><a href="shoppingcart.php?action=delete&id='.$id.'">Remove</a></td>';
                $total += $cartrow['cake_price'] * $qty;
                $output[] = '</tr>';
            }
            }
        }
        $output[] = '</table>';
        $output[] = '</div>';
        $output[] = '<p>Grand total: <strong>&pound;'.$total.'</strong></p>';
        $output[] = '<div class="\"formlabels\"><button type="submit">Update Cart</button></div>';
        $output[] = '</form>';
    } else {
        $output[] = '<p>Your shopping cart is empty.</p>';
    }
    echo join('
                ',$output);
    }
```

?>

Comment: What format can your products' names be in? You've got characters and an underscore in your example, but can you have numbers? Apostophes? Quotes?

Comment: all the urls are just like vanilla_cupcakes no numbers, basically one word underscore one word

Comment: you can write a function to check that the text is in that format, in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's [is_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php) function is what you are looking for. If none of your product names contain digits you could also simply do a `!is_numeric`.

Comment: (1) `is_numeric('abc123def') will return `false` even though there are digits in the string; (2) theoretically, there's no need for testing at all in his case apart from testing that the `$id` is not empty.  However his sql code will have to change, most likely.

Comment: Indeed, I would change the test to check that the id isn't empty.

Comment: !is_numeric doesnot work throws up and error.. i have uploaded the whole code if can figure it out from that? many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your `$id` is a string rather than a number, then you don't need to check whether it's numeric or not. In fact, you only need to check whether it's not empty, such as

```
if(strlen(trim($id)) {
    $cartresult = mysql_query($sql);
```

**However!** You will almost certainly need to modify how your `$sql` is built.  You're not showing it in your code, but it has to be done somewhere before the `mysql_query` line.  You'll probably end up with something like

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;port=portnum;dbname=databasename', 'username', 'password');

if(strlen(trim($id)) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE id=?";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_ISTR);
    $sth->execute();

    while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that this example is using PDO rather than `mysql_` set of function, which is deprecated anyway.  You should probably start using PDO, as it's a lot more versatile and secure (if used properly).